# Unable to create email alias because it already exists, but cannot find the instance of it

Tags: email, powershell, microsoft-office-365, alias, microsoft-office

**Error:**

> An Azure Active Directory call was made to keep object in sync between
> Azure Active Directory and Exchange Online. However, it failed.
> Detailed error message: Another object with the same value for
> property EmailAddresses already exists. The issue may be transient and
> please retry a couple of minutes later. If issue persists, please see
> exception members for more information.

**Issue:**

I'm trying to add an email alias to a user:

> User: joe@email.com
>
> Alias: joe@newemail.com

However, whenever I try to add this alias, it reports that the address exists, and I'm not sure why.

I checked with Powershell with this command:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity * | Where-Object {$_.EmailAddresses -like 'smtp:joe@newemail.com'} | Format-List Identity, EmailAddresses
```

But it doesn't find anything ... I have no idea where this address is to remove it, so I can add it to the users mailbox.

[Edit]

I should have mentioned as well, that when you try to send an email to joe@newemail.com it bounces back saying that it does not exists.

Comment: Try using the wildcard character (*) as `$_.EmailAddresses -like '*joe@newemail.com'`…

Comment: I've had this problem, too - and the email address is attached to a guest account - you know, those psuedo logins created when someone shares a file to a person without a regular 365 account - like when you share a file to a gmail user or whatever.

Comment: I have to go into exchange and find them there.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be a mailbox, it may be a contact or distribution group. Try this:

`Get-Recipient | Select DisplayName, RecipientType, EmailAddresses | Export-CSV c:\temp\recpients.csv`

Then review the csv file and do a search for the alias to find the object with the alias.

Comment: This yielded no results. I should have mentioned as well, that when you try to send an email to joe@newemail.com it bounces back saying that it does not exists. (Appending this to main question)

Comment: OK. Office 365 support is free. It might be quicker at this point to open a support case from your Office 365 tenant and have them assist you in tracking it down.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to office 365 admin portal, you may search for the email id on the home page. If there is any id created, it will return a result. You may also try running idfix tool https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/install-and-run-idfix

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using Outlook, you could start composing a new message to this email address, and use the Check Names feature to resolve the recipient.

Alternatively, you could try to send an email to the address and use the Message Tracing feature (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/monitoring/trace-an-email-message/run-a-message-trace-and-view-results) to uncover more details. I have not tested this second approach yet.

Answer (score 0):

What my feeling is when you look for SMTP address, the problem itself could be the duplication of alias itself.

**Below message suggest, the account you are trying to edit, may not be editable at all ..**

```
An Azure Active Directory call was made to keep object in sync between Azure Active Directory and Exchange Online. However, it failed. Detailed error message: Another object with the same value for property EmailAddresses already exists. The issue may be transient and please retry a couple of minutes later. If issue persists, please see exception members for more information.
```

regardless trying to add an extra alias or anything.. try changing any other attribute other than adding alias, it shoiuld fail to save !

If that is the case you already have duplicate alias..

**Alias referred is not necessarily a SMTP address!**

[image]

Give it a try....

```
 Get-Mailbox -Identity * -ResultSize unlimited | Where-Object {$_.Alias -like '*joe*'} |select name,alias
```

and

```
Get-Recipient -ResultSize unlimited | Where-Object {$_.Alias -like '*joe*'}
```

and

```
get-distributiongroup -ResultSize unlimited | Where-Object {$_.Alias -like '*joe*'}
```

If it yields a result for above, you should consider altering the alias visible duplicated above..

Then try to change add/edit account you tried.